# Default threading model for a .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am new to programming, so please pardon me for if the question is a silly one-

I want to know that, in an ordinary C# program where we don't create multi-threads manually in  the code, does the whole program run on a single main thread OR
there are some other threads created for the execution of program?

Comment: Something has to tell the application to use another thread. It doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: Depending on the configuration the [garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#concurrent_garbage_collection) may run in an extra thread.

Comment: C# uses explicit parallelism meaning you as a programmer are in control of threads and need to explicitly launch additional threads.  Implicit parallelism isn't very practical currently as it requires a fairly in depth knowledge of the specific functionality of the program. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_parallelism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, there are other threads with the main thread that are required to support the application.

This can be tested in Visual Studio.

Create a simple Console application. Put a debug point, and start debugging. Once the application gets to that debug point, open "Threads" windows by

```
Debug -> Windows -> Threads
```

You will see something like:

[image]

Some of the above threads are for debugger, but mostly an app would have main thread, GC (Garbage Collection) and Finalizer thread etc.

Comment: typically GC and Finalizer run on separate threads. If that is what you are asking... See more on.. https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/ (`The finalizer typically runs on its own thread. If you have an object that is in some way has affinity to a particular thread`)

Answer (score 4):

From [Threading (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679045.aspx):

> By default, a C# program has one thread. However, auxiliary threads
>   can be created and used to execute code in parallel with the primary
>   thread.